# .htaccess content converstion to Web.config content

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

I have this url re-write rules in .htaccess in Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I know wish to convert it into Web.config contents in II7

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?route={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Is it seemed to be correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but your added conditions are wrong. The condition that you have is that the request + ".html" is a file. What you want is:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
```

That's equvalent to the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

part of the apache rewrite rules.

So:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?route={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I put the codes in action but seems no response. Do I have to do some configurations in the IIs server? Thanks